# pgfplots combining expression with marks at fixed x coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like pgfplots to draw an expression together with marks at pre-specified coordinates and/or fixed intervals. For instance, to plot the function 1/x as a line together with marks at discrete values 1, 2, ..., 10.

This is the desired output:

[image]

This is my first failed attempt: based on the `samples' option. I want the points to be at fixed intervals, not random intervals (besides with a small value of samples the line becomes jagged, so not a good approach):

[image]

This is my second failed attempt: specifying the `mark indices' option.

[image]

I expected this last one to work. Am I doing it wrong? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

% Workaround: specify the data points
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title = {use `coordinates'}, xtick = {0,1,...,10}, grid = both]
\addplot [mark=*] coordinates {(1,1) (2,0.5) (3,0.33) (4,0.25) (5,0.2) (6,0.167) (7,0.143) (8,0.125) (9,0.111) (10,0.1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Desired approach: specify the expression and show marks at 1-unit intervals

% attempt 1: 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title = {use `samples'}, xtick = {0,1,...,10}, grid = both]
\addplot [domain = 0:10, mark=*, samples = 10] expression {1/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% attempt 2: 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title = {use `mark indices'}, xtick = {0,1,...,10}, grid = both]
\addplot [domain = 0:10, mark=*, mark indices = {0,1,...,10}] expression {1/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `samples at` key:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title = {use \texttt{samples at =<coordinate list>}}, xtick = {0,1,...,10}, grid = both]
\addplot [domain = 0:10, mark=*, samples at = {1,...,10}] expression {1/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To answer the comment regarding smoothness, one can use two `\addplot` commands, one with `draw=none` just to put the marks and the other with more `samples` to draw the curve as below:

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title = {use \texttt{samples at =<coordinate list>}}, xtick = {0,1,...,10}, grid = both]
\addplot [domain = 1:10, mark=none, samples=100] expression {1/x};
\addplot [draw=none,domain = 0:10, mark=*, samples at = {1,...,10}] expression {1/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for this speedy reply! How about if I want to mark selected points, but I still want the line graphing the expression to be smooth? (samples seems to interpolate linearly, as far as I can view from the output) perhaps a smooth option on top of the `samples at' option? [your answer is correct, since I did not specifically ask for the line to be smooth in my OP!]

Comment: @PatrickT Please see the update.

Answer (score 4):

You have 10 intervals of equal length. The first sample is at the start of the plot and the last is at the end of the plot. So you need at least `samples=11` (1+10*1). If there should be 20 samples between two marks you need `samples=201` (1+10*20). Then you can use something like

```
mark phase=0,mark repeat=20,samples=201
```

or

```
mark indices={1,21,...,201},samples=201
```

Note that `mark phase` starts with `0` while `mark indices`starts with `1`.

```
\documentclass[border=3pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}

% Desired approach: specify the expression and show marks at 1-unit intervals

% attempt 1: 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title = {use `samples and smooth'}, xtick = {0,1,...,10}, grid = both]
\addplot [domain = 0:10, mark=*, samples = 11,smooth] expression {1/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% attempt 2: 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title = {use `mark phase and mark repeat'}, xtick = {0,1,...,10}, grid = both]
\addplot [restrict y to domain=0:1,domain = 0:10, mark=*,mark phase=0,mark repeat=20,samples=201] expression {1/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% attempt 3: 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title = {use `mark indices'}, xtick = {0,1,...,10}, grid = both]
\addplot [restrict y to domain=0:1,domain = 0:10, mark=*,mark indices={1,21,...,201},samples=201] expression {1/x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, this is very useful. I selected Harish's answer because he preceded you a little, but your answer is excellent. Thank you. :-)